# In Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny, would this event remain hidden from archeologists?

Tags: indiana-jones, indiana-jones-the-dial-of-destiny

Big spoiler below.

At the end of Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny,

> Indiana Jones and the Nazis go back in time to Syracuse in 213 B.C.

During the battle,

> a lot of Nazis soliders died on the battlefield and the plane crashes near the city. The plane, the soldiers uniforms, weapons and bullets are not exactly biodegradable and I guess it would be difficult to hide or make them totally disappear, even on a 2,000 years timeframe.

Wouldn't archeologists have found some remains long before 1969 when the movie happens? Or at least, such an event could have been documented.

Is there any reason why the remains were not discovered?

Comment: Archeological excavations around Syracuse started in the first half of the XIX century and they continued one way or another after the union of Italy and in the XX century. So it's reasonable to assume that the wreck could be found and would raise several questions, all the more if it happened when there weren't planes or petrol engines around. However, 2100 years is a long time: the plane could have been thrown in the sea by the Romans, they may have destroyed it while trying to repurpose it, they may have have moved it and lost the ship that was carrying it, the records could be lost...

Comment: This might be a [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaeology) or  it could be a [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) question... Not sure. But, its not impossible, remains from civil war battlefields ~200 years ago are pretty badly degraded. It takes special conditions for things to be preserved.

Comment: She tells the genius that, "*He* can't stay here." He then presumably puts two and two together to equal zero by hiding the plane in a cave and disguising it with pinball machine parts. Although he can't help himself from putting propellers on depictions of the phoenix. We have documents from the last movie that aliens built the pyramids, and plenty of accounts of fire breathing dragons from all of history. But that's not *science*. - Anyways, don't you worry. We have top men working on it.

Comment: Remove "I guess". Now it isn't a real world science question. The half life of lead is 50k years, or stable. And copper is also stable ... "(i.e. no radioactivity has been observed for them) are predicted to have extremely long half-lives (sometimes as high as 10^18 years or more)." And those are two things you build water pipes out of due to their low reactivity (with oxygen). They *are not* biodegradable. Picchu sat for 400 years *in the open* w/o being discovered. But the last line might need to ask *what fills this plot hole.*

Comment: Note to close voters: it's not a "real world science" question to ask how something works, or how it is explained, _in-universe_.

Comment: OK, so, Neow, are you asking how this is explained *in-universe*, or are you asking if this is *realistically, scientifically, possible in the real world*?  If you mean *in-universe*, could you please edit that into the question?  Then perhaps we can reopen this.

Comment: In universe the incident is only briefly mentioned, unless there are other works that reference this, surely any answer would be more real world than in universe

Comment: @SQB - I think the "is it realistic" part of the question is clearly prompting us to apply real world logic rather than in-universe logic. If it were purely asking from an in-universe perspective, then the answer to the question of whether the event would remain hidden or not should be self-evident: if it did remain hidden in the movie, then yes it would. It if didn't, then it wouldn't.

Comment: @Basya to me the Indiana Jones universe is realistic until it's not. Physics apply normally until you sit inside a boat  and jump from a plane. So the best answer is an in-universe answer. Otherwise real world rules should apply.

Comment: @LogicDictates but that's not necessarily a problem. The unwritten rule is that unless contradicted, real world logic applies. So I agree with you that the question could be phrased better, for instance "how come the remains weren't discovered in the years since?"

Comment: @SQB - This isn't an issue of poor phrasing. The alternative phrasing you're proposing -- _"Why weren't the remains discovered?"_ -- is simply a different question altogether than the actual question asked here: _"Is it realistic that the remains weren't discovered?"_ If you want to change the fundamental meaning of the question to save it from closure, that's fine, but the question as currently written was rightfully closed, and should not have been reopened until the wording was significantly altered (which it still hasn't been).

Comment: @Neow - it would be great if you would edit that into the question.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (but unspoken) explanation would be that Archimedes himself has all the debris from the future hidden or disposed of.

During the encounter with Indy and Helena, Archimedes learns that the dial works, that these people are from a distant future where his name is still revered, that this event isn't part of their history, and that if Indy stays in the past that future is at risk. That gives Archimedes motive to, if nothing else, vainly preserve his legacy by removing evidence of future machinery.

Historically the people of Syracuse repelled the Roman attacks that began in 213 BC -- reputedly in part due to Archimedes' devices -- and the Romans settled in to what would turn into a months-long siege. Archimedes would eventually be killed by Roman soldiers who snuck into the city during a festival, but this gives the fictional Archimedes months to act. During that time we know he completes the dial and either builds or arranges for the completion of his tomb, which is no small project. That also gives him time to have supporters collect debris and other evidence of the crashed bomber and the Nazis. How can he get people to do that? He *is* the savior of the city, after all.

Presumably anyone with the resources to have the tomb built and hidden in such a way that won't be found for 2,200 years can also deal with disposing of a few tons of metal and other materials. A further rationalization would be that Archimedes incorporated those very materials into the tomb, since we do find the watch on his remains and Indy sees that the sarcophagus is decorated with anachronistic images of an airplane and more.

As for written accounts of the bomber shooting up the Romans and effectively repelling the attack, well, the historical literature already credits Archimedes with repelling the attacks with implausible devices. What's one more implausible invention?